# Background Top Repeat

Tags: html, css

I'm converting [this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxmwt.jpg) to HTML & CSS format.

I get stucked when it comes to repeat background top since the left part and right part is not using same image file.

I've tried using [this trick](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-backgrounds-left-half-and-right-half/), but it did not work for me.

I wish to repeat these files and have the header at the middle (header.jpg):

- top-left: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcuph.jpg
- top-right: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruG9M.jpg

I also tried background-position, but did not work for me.

What should I do my friends?

Thank you.

Comment: Here is the header URL: http://i.imgur.com/vRy9S.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure i understand your question, but I think this is what you are after:
http://jsfiddle.net/ub66M/1/

the html looks like this:

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header-left"><!-- empty, just for background --></div>
    <div id="header-right"><!-- empty, just for background --></div>
    <div id="header-center">
        the actual content of the header comes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css looks something like this:

```
#header-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#header-left, #header-right {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 284px;
    z-index: -1;
}
#header-left {
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/tcr1F.jpg);
}
#header-right {
  left: 50%; 
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/PchTG.jpg);
}
#header-center {
    width: 500px; /* adapt to actual width of center slice */
    height: 284px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/500x284) no-repeat; /* put your center slice here */
}
```

The trick lies in adding two extra divs, and position them absolute behind the actual content of the header. The center div off course has to contain the correct, non repeating, slice of image, and the actual content of the header.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it should be better to repeat-y the background and to be background of w `<div class=wrapper>` which wrap all the site content, or something like this ... and cut bigger crop.. not just 1 pixel height, but about 50-60

Answer (score 0):

If I were building this design, I'd just take a horizontal slice (15-20 pixels or so) of the pink to orange background, and set it to `repeat-y` on the `<body>`.  That pink top and bottom border around the main content looks like just that - a pink border for top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can't accurately express that header with those 2 images because it isn't a horizontal *or* vertical gradient.  It's on a diagonal.  You could, however, do it quite easily with CSS gradients.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZteRf/

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff3232 0%, #fff989 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff3232), color-stop(100%,#fff989)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff3232 0%,#fff989 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff3232 0%,#fff989 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff3232 0%,#fff989 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #ff3232 0%,#fff989 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3232', endColorstr='#fff989',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Thank you my friend. Good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your css

```
   body
   {
   background-image:url("http://s8.postimage.org/r3vb8vx2t/NEIPb.jpg");
   background-repeat:repeat-y;
   }
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/v4zTT/ (Drag inbetween javascript and result you can see full image)

Good Luck..:)

Comment: Thank you my friend. But, this is not what I want. I want to repeat-x the top-left and top-right image. The header image at the middle.